# Adding users to existing database table in RoR webapp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, seed

I am hosting my web app with Heroku and I have a seeds.rb which I use to push users to the database using `heroku run rake db:seed`, but I currently have a baseline of users I don't want to overwrite. Is it possible to create a seeds2.rb file with those users and run `heroku run rake db:seed`, but use the seeds2.rb file instead? (Or something like that)

Comment: Do you mean to say that the `seeds2.rb` will add additional users? Could you create a snippet showing expected output?

Comment: You could do this with a migration instead, then `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

Comment: What would the migration look like? I'd like to add a bunch of users with code like `User.create!(first_name: "Bob", last_name: "Saget", email: "test@reset.com", phone: "111-111-1111", password: "...", password_confirmation: "...", activated: true, activated_at: Time.zone.now)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You could create a directory of database seed scripts and specify which seed script you want to run in the `seed.rb` file.

This is the proposed directory structure:

```
db
| - seeds
|    | - initial_users_seed.rb
|    | - seed2.rb
|
| - seed.rb
```

The `initial_users_seed.rb` will contain the code that was previously in `seed.rb`. You then replace the code in `seed.rb` with code to execute the `seed2.rb` script:

**seed.rb**

```
require 'seed2.rb'
```

Comment: Would simply replacing the contents of the current seeds.rb, saving the old contents in a seeds_initial.rb file, and running `heroku run rake db:seed` work? Or would that delete current DB entries?

Comment: If your seed script does not clear the database, it won't delete current DB entries. The command simply executes the seed script.